# Inserting and evaluating a column in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a formula to a column but it is just stored as text and not evaluated, and if I add the "=" sign, it will return an error. Is there any way to tell excel to evaluate the complete column at the end or even better is there a proper way to write the formula?

```vb
    Dim arreglo_formulas() As Variant
    'If Error, Index, Match in spanish excel, I get an error if I add "=" before the plus sign
    arreglo_formulas() = Array("+SI.ERROR(INDICE(CASOS_ESPECIALES[Saldo Proyección];COINCIDIR([@Llave];CASOS_ESPECIALES[Llave];0));[@[Distribución]]*[@[Saldo Balance Sheet]])")
    Call AgregaFilas(table_name, arreglo_formulas)

    Sub AgregaFilas(ByVal nombre_tabla As String, arrData As Variant)
        Dim Tbl As ListObject
        Dim NewRow As ListRow
        Set Tbl = Range(nombre_tabla).ListObject
        Set NewRow = Tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

        ' Handle Arrays and Ranges
        If TypeName(arrData) = "Range" Then
            NewRow.Range = arrData.Value
        Else
            NewRow.Range = arrData
        End If

    End Sub
```

Biggest problem is that this code works but the formula is not evaluated so I have to go row by row "pressing enter" to evaluate it.

Comment: Please post some sample data

Comment: What is the error that you get? If the error is in VBA, what line is highlighted? If you write the formula into the table, does it work?  Why are you using the `Array` function to try to create the formula.

Comment: AFAIK it's necessary to define the formulae in English, not in the regional setting (including differences in argument delimiters such as ";" or "," :-)

Comment: [This may prove useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.FormulaLocal)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the error is 1004, "Error defined by application or object" in 
` NewRow.Range = arrData `

Comment: @T.M. I don't know why it didn't use to work when I wrote the formula in english but now it does :)! Thank you very much!

Comment: @eduardo0 I see you have your answer.  That error is because the formula, as written in the cell by VBA, is incorrect.